# CheckBox Issues: item selection & SQLite Database - ANDROID

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, insert, sqlite

I'm having CheckBox issues. Well two issues.

1. When I check item in the checkbox, other item is also checked.
2. I can't capture the name(after it's checked) into SQLiteDatabase table.

My app has a ListView of contacts names(retrieved from android built-in contacts list) and checkbox. Plus, the user can multi-select the names in the list.
I've 2 classes within one class
1. `public class ContactsList`
2.`public class MyCustomAdapter`

Here are my codes:
ContactsList.java - **UPDATED MY CODES**

public class ContactsList extends ListActivity
{
    static ArrayList friendsList = new ArrayList();

```
ListView list;
private ContactsList[] friends;
private ArrayAdapter<ContactsList> listAdapter;

final Context context = this;

Cursor cursor;

String[] buddiesList = 
    {"Kanak Priya",
    "Joanne Liew",
    "Michelle Lam",
    "Teo Kin Hua",
    "Melissa Haiting",
    "David Yeo",
    "Natasha Akhbar",
    "Gillian Gan",
    "Sonia",
    "Ms Long",
    "Joan Tang",
    "Stephanie",
    "Nur Ashiqin"
    };

BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(ContactsList.this, R.layout.contacts_list, buddiesList));
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.contacts_list, buddiesList));

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //ListView list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id)
        {
            ContactsList friends = listAdapter.getItem(position);
            friends.**toggleChecked**();
            ContactsListViewHolder viewHolder = (ContactsListViewHolder) view.getTag();
            viewHolder.**getCheckBox**().setChecked(friends.**isChecked**());


            Cursor cursor = null;

               cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
               Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsList.this, Create_Events.class);
               intent.putExtra("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(buddyDB.KEY_NAME)));
               startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

    ContactsList[] arrContacts = friendsList.toArray(new ContactsList[0]);


    Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");

    Cursor c = managedQuery(allContacts, null, null, null, null);

    String[] columns = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int[] views = new int[]  {R.id.contactName};

    startManagingCursor(c);

    SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
    this.setListAdapter(friendsAdapter);
}

private static class ContactsName
{
    private String name = "";
    private boolean checked = false;

    public ContactsName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isChecked()
    {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked)
    {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void toggleChecked()
    {
        checked = !checked;
    }
}

private static class ContactsListViewHolder
{
    private CheckBox nameCheck;
    private TextView contactName;

    public ContactsListViewHolder(TextView contactName, CheckBox nameCheck)
    {
        this.nameCheck = nameCheck;
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public CheckBox getNameCheck()
    {
        return nameCheck;
    }

    public TextView getContactName()
    {
        return contactName;
    }
}

private static class ContactsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactsList>
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ContactsCustomAdapter(Context context, List<ContactsList> friendsList)
    {
        **super(context, R.layout.contacts_list, R.id.contactName,  R.id.contactCheckbox, friendsList);**
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ContactsList friends = (ContactsList) this.getItem(position);

        CheckBox nameCheck;
        TextView contactName;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list, null);

            contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            nameCheck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactCheckbox);

            convertView.setTag(new ContactsListViewHolder(contactName, nameCheck));

            nameCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        ContactsList friends = (ContactsList) cb.getTag();
                        friends.**setChecked**(cb.isChecked());

                        if(cb.isChecked())
                        {
                            friendsList.add(friends.**name**);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            friendsList.remove(friends.**name**);
                        }
                    }   
                });
        }
        else
        {
            ContactsListViewHolder viewHolder = (ContactsListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            nameCheck = viewHolder.**getCheckBox**();
            contactName = viewHolder.**getTexView**();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    buddyDB.open();
    long name_id;
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor cursor = null;

       cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
       Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsList.this, Create_Events.class);
       intent.putExtra("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(buddyDB.KEY_NAME)));
       startActivity(intent);

    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setChoiceMode(2);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    l.setItemChecked(position, l.isItemChecked(position));

    Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
    c.moveToPosition(position);

    TextView contactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
    String NameValue = contactName.getText().toString();        
    name_id = buddyDB.insertNames(NameValue);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Selected: " + buddiesList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
    buddyDB.close();



}
```

}

**NOTE**
THe codes i've bold up means those are the errors I've got. It asking for create method for `isChecked(), toggleChecked(), setChecked() and getCheckBox()`.

Asking to create field type or constant type for `name` but I've already created it

```
private static class ContactsName
    {
        private String name = "";
```

I'm not sure where I've coded wrong. I need to able to insert the names into database table and I want to make sure that when I check a name, other names shouldn't be checked. Anyone can help me out?
Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with Planet names as an example, just change the Strings to the contact names:

```
public class PlanetsActivity extends Activity {
static ArrayList<String> FavList = new ArrayList<String>();

  private ListView mainListView ;
  private Planet[] planets ;
  private ArrayAdapter<Planet> listAdapter ;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    // Find the ListView resource. 
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

// When item is tapped, toggle checked properties of CheckBox and Planet.
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View item, 
                           int position, long id) {
    Planet planet = listAdapter.getItem( position );
    planet.toggleChecked();
    PlanetViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetViewHolder) item.getTag();
    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked( planet.isChecked() );
  }
});


    // Create and populate planets.
planets = (Planet[]) getLastNonConfigurationInstance() ;
if ( planets == null ) {
  planets = new Planet[] { 
      new Planet("Mercury"), new Planet("Venus"), new Planet("Earth"), 
      new Planet("Mars"), new Planet("Jupiter"), new Planet("Saturn"), 
      new Planet("Uranus"), new Planet("Neptune"), new Planet("Ceres"),
      new Planet("Pluto"), new Planet("Haumea"), new Planet("Makemake"),
      new Planet("Eris")
      };  
    }
ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

// Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.
listAdapter = new PlanetArrayAdapter(this, planetList);
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
  }

  /** Holds planet data. */
  private static class Planet {
  private String name = "" ;
  private boolean checked = false ;
  public Planet( String name ) {
  this.name = name ;
}
public String getName() {
  return name;
}
public boolean isChecked() {
  return checked;
}
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
  this.checked = checked;
}
public String toString() {
  return name ; 
}
public void toggleChecked() {
  checked = !checked ;
    }
  }

  /** Holds child views for one row. */
  private static class PlanetViewHolder {
private CheckBox checkBox ;
private TextView textView ;
public PlanetViewHolder( TextView textView, CheckBox checkBox ) {
  this.checkBox = checkBox ;
  this.textView = textView ;
}
public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
  return checkBox;
}
public TextView getTextView() {
  return textView;
}    
  }

  /** Custom adapter for displaying an array of Planet objects. */
  private static class PlanetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PlanetArrayAdapter( Context context, List<Planet> planetList ) {
      super( context, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView, planetList );
      // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // Planet to display
      Planet planet = (Planet) this.getItem( position ); 

      // The child views in each row.
      CheckBox checkBox ; 
      TextView textView ; 

      // Create a new row view
      if ( convertView == null ) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);

      // Find the child views.
      textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.rowTextView );
      checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.CheckBox01 );

    // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have to 
    // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
    convertView.setTag( new PlanetViewHolder(textView,checkBox) );

    // If CheckBox is toggled, update the planet it is tagged with.
    checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
        Planet planet = (Planet) cb.getTag();
        planet.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );

        if (cb.isChecked()){
            FavList.add(planet.name);
        }
        else{
            FavList.remove(planet.name);
        }
      }
    });        
  }
  // Reuse existing row view
  else {
    // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call findViewById().
    PlanetViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox() ;
    textView = viewHolder.getTextView() ;
  }

  // Tag the CheckBox with the Planet it is displaying, so that we can
  // access the planet in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
  checkBox.setTag( planet ); 

  // Display planet data
  checkBox.setChecked( planet.isChecked() );
  textView.setText( planet.getName() );      

  return convertView;
}

  }

  public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return planets ;
  }

  public void comments (View view) {
  Intent myintent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), DB.class);
  myintent.putExtra("name", FavList);
  startActivity(myintent);
  }
}
```

And the DB.class looks like:

```
public class DB extends ListActivity {

private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "myFriendsDb";
private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friend";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<String> NumList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("name");
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {
        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (FirstName VARCHAR);");

        for(String str: NumList){
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                        " ( FirstName ) Values ('"+str+"');");
            }


        Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName FROM " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " where FirstName > 10 LIMIT 5", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                    results.add("" + firstName);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (sampleDB != null) 
            sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
            sampleDB.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'll try to understand your codes and test it out on my app. =)

Comment: hi, no worries, please let me know if you can't get it to work :)

Comment: hi again, in your codes your String array where you list out planets, did you hardcode your String array? because, in my app, my string array `String[] buddiesList`where I list out the names, is for Toast message but I commented it out. The names in the String array are not from the Android built-in contacts list. and I'm not sure if i need to code my String array or not.

Comment: well, yes. The android phone's contacts are in the list. whenever an user adds a contact name in the phone, it goes into my ListView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16680/discussion-between-fasheikh-and-miyayayayami)